# Word Separators for Text Editor in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How can I set the Word Separators for Visual Studio 2017.  Right now Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right stop at too many places, even compared to VS2008.  Can someone point out where that is setup?

TIA!!